# phonegap customize camera

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android-camera

The phonegap uses the default camera layout of the device in the getPicture function

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI ,targetWidth: 500});
```

Is there a way to customize this, I need the image capture to be a square and hide the excess height since i will crop it out after taking the picture.

Thanks

Comment: I saw some people create custom camera using native language + xml can phonegap call something like this and go back to index after taking picture?